# Confusion upon the difference between Java Client and Java Server

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

From my understanding the Java Client is what is rendered onto the browser such as the javascript, "the client side" for example what the user see's (tables, html, the sorting etc) things in the jsp. The server side is the servlet that makes the connection and call the specific class's based upon the request. I feel as though I am completely wrong as when I do research I am getting different answers. CAn I get some clarification on this please.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model

Answer (score 0):

Java running on the client side means the end user needs Java installed and is running a Java program on their computer. This could be a standalone Java executable program (a traditional application), or it could be through a browser running a Java applet. Either way the end user's computer is actually running the Java code locally.

Java on the server side means that all the Java processing happens on a server somewhere, and the person accessing the site or service doesn't need Java installed. Servlets and JSPs fall into this category. The server does all the processing and then returns HTML/Javascript/CSS, etc to the end user. The user's web browser receives and processes those files to display the web site.

It sounds like you are getting confused because web browsers use Javascript to display dynamic sites, but Javascript is a totally separate language that has nothing to do with Java. In other words, a web site could be powered by Java servlets on the back end and could also use Javascript on the front-end, but they aren't directly related or dependent on each other. All the HTML, Javascript, CSS, etc that make up the web site are processed by the user's browser and the user doesn't have to know or care how all that stuff is generated on the back end.